# Silex Exception handler

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have big problem I don't know why exceptions are not catch by silex exception handler ?

My simple Code looks like this:

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;

use Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app = new Application();

// SPL Logic Exceptions
// Handle other exception as 500 errors
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) {
exit('asd');
});
throw new Exception('test');
return $app;
```

And the result is:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'test'**

Comment: Did you also try throwing an exception inside an action? I don't think exceptions outside of normal request handling (`$app->run()`) are caught.

Comment: @Maerlyn is right, your exceptions are not caught in the front controller. Exceptions are caught in your source code though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `error` listener is only able to catch exceptions thrown from within a controller or a `before` middleware. Here's an example that works:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) {
    exit('asd');
});

$app->before(function ($request) {
    throw new Exception('test');
});

$app->run();
```