# Why does the silex error handler not run?

Tags: php, exception, silex

I have a silex application. I have a catch a generic handler registered:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {
    return (new JsonResponse(['message' => 'Something truly horrible happened. Sorry.', 500)])->send();
    }
);
```

Yet when something is throwing an exception in `$app::share()`, it does not trigger:

```
$app->share(function () {
    throw new \Exception('wtf');
}));
```

This exception will not be handled by the error handler but pops up directly as if there was no handler in place at all:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'wtf' in appinit.php:230
Stack trace: #0 ./vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php(126): Closure$#12() #1 ./vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php(83): Closure$Pimple::share() #2 ./web/appinit.php(234): Pimple->offsetGet() #3 app.php(6): include() #4 {main}
```

I just expected a basic 400 Bad Request response with the content:

```
{
  "message": "Something truly horrible happened. Sorry.",
}
```

Why does my handler not activate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silex Exception handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311508/silex-exception-handler)

Comment: I don't thing it's related to the question you post. Did you run this code with the run flag on (```$app['debug'] = true```)? If so, can you turn it off and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In silex the error handler only handles exceptions occurring on Middlewares. So in fact, the error is never called and this is by design as the exception occurs on:

```
try {
    $app->run()
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // this will be caught
}
```